# If “were tired” is correct grammatically, why is “was studied” not?

Tags: grammaticality, sentence, past-tense, simple-past

I was practicing english and I have a question.

Why is it correct to write:

> We **were** so **tired**.

But it is not correct to write:

> I **was** **studied** english.

I know that it is correct to write:

> I studied english.

But I don’t know why in the first sentence, I can use the auxiliary "were" when the verb is "tired" and, in the second sentence I can't use the auxiliary "was" when the verb is "studied".

I am confused.

Answer (score 1):

Both words may be used as adjectives. *I was tired* describes me as being tired (by work, exercise, boredom, etc). *I was studied* describes me as being studied (by a doctor, a psychologist, an anthropologist etc).

*I was studied English* makes no sense because *studied* is used as a verb and the verbal noun phrase “studied English” is meaninglessly adjectival when applied to “I”.

“Studied English” might be used as a noun phrase in a sentence such as “The author used studied English to express herself, rather than using colloquial English”

Comment: Another important point is that "studied" is a transitive verb. One could use "was studied" as a possible form, but as part of the passive "English was studied by me".

Answer (score 0):

"We were tired" indicates that you were all suffering from the condition of being tired and that condition was continuous at the time you were speaking of. For instance "We *were* so tired last night that we went to bed early, but now we have had a good sleep we *are* all ready for some more work this morning"

In contrast "I studied English", "I have studied English" and "I had studied English" mean that at the time at which, or about which, you were speaking the action of studying was complete. That is you weren't doing it any more. If you wanted to say that, at some time in the past your studies were continuing you would say "In 2014 I *was studying* English". Notice that because the studying was continuing in 2014 you use 'was' but you combine it with *studying* rather than *studied* because *studying* indicates continuous activity.